# Extracting specific column data from huge data file in Python

Tags: python

I have a huge data file which contains data in this format:

```
[06/Nov/2016:23:24:03 +0100] BIND REQ conn=8349228 op=0 msgID=1 version=3 type=SIMPLE dn="uid=user1,ou=Org1,ou=example,o=com"
[06/Nov/2016:23:24:03 +0100] BIND REQ conn=8349229 op=0 msgID=1 version=3 type=SIMPLE dn="uid=user2,ou=Org1,ou=example,o=com"
[06/Nov/2016:23:24:04 +0100] BIND REQ conn=8349230 op=0 msgID=1 version=3 type=SIMPLE dn="uid=user3,ou=Org1,ou=example,o=com"
[06/Nov/2016:23:24:04 +0100] BIND REQ conn=8349231 op=0 msgID=1 version=3 type=SIMPLE dn="uid=user4,ou=Org1,ou=example,o=com"
```

I want to extract the uids from this text file, and the resulting output should look like this:

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

I used this code to extract these values:

```
with open("C:\\test") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        print(str(str(line.split(" ")[9]).split("=")[2]).split(",")[0])
```

but I am getting the error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: How does the offending line look like? You could modify the code like this: `try: for line... except: print(line)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a regex:

Here's an example with one line of text from your data file.

```
import re

s = '[06/Nov/2016:23:24:03 +0100] BIND REQ conn=8349228 op=0 msgID=1 version=3 type=SIMPLE dn="uid=user1,ou=Org1,ou=example,o=com"'

print re.findall(r'uid=(.*?),',s)[0]
# prints user1
```

Working example: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user42_0jDArlYoNk_0.py

---

Update

You maybe be encountering an error if you have a string that doesn't contain a userid. Therefore you could try a `try/except` or something like this:

```
import re

s = '[06/Nov/2016:23:24:03 +0100] BIND REQ conn=8349228 op=0 msgID=1 version=3 type=SIMPLE dn="uid=user1,ou=Org1,ou=example,o=com"'

errors= []

result = re.findall(r'uid=(.*?),',s)

if len(result):
    print result[0]
else:
    errors.append(s)


if len(errors):
    print "\n Errors were encountered with the following strings"
    for error in errors:
        print error
```

Code can be found
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user42_0jDArlYoNk_1.py

Comment: I am still getting this
**`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/File handling/test-py.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(re.findall(r'uid=(.*?),', line)[0])
IndexError: list index out of range`**

I guess the issue does not pops up with 1 line of code or even 1000 lines, my file has more than 500,000 lines of code, it breaks when i used this regex **`re.findall(r'uid=(.*?),',s)[0]`** or even my solution **`print(str(str(line.split(" ")[9]).split("=")[2]).split(",")[0])`** for entire file.

For few lines of data both the codes work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Rough guess that your input file contains empty line or some line that doesn't fulfill the data format. Try below

```
with open("C:\\test") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if 'uid=' in line:
            print line.split()[-1].split('=')[2].split(',')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply suggest to run the debugger and look at which `line` in `fh` it crashes. Maybe too obvious but good chance it works.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out there were some lines in the file which were having white spaces " " after the uid field, so I split the file another way and it seemed to work for me. This is how I split the file.

```
print(line.split()[-1].split(",")[0])
```